# How can I better prepare for roles that require selenium and java knowledge?

Tags: selenium, java

Many companies are giving test engineers quizzes and questions when they are interviewing.

I have a great deal of key knowledge about the business domain and I'm able to add a lot of value with that knowledge.  However when it comes to quizzes and questions which seem to focus on programming knowledge I am lost.

I am currently looking to work with Selenium and Java.
How can I improve my knowledge in those areas?

Comment: Made an attempt to create an answerable question.  I think we should do more of this instead of closing so we can _encourage new members_ at the point they first encounter the site.  Hopefully this will grow our base and they they will ask more questions / provide answers and _that_ will grow our site more.  I feel it's not so much about this question but about the persons potential future contributions.

Comment: "I am currently looking to work with Selenium and Java. How can I improve my knowledge in those areas?" - study Selenium and Java in order to improve your programming knowledge. You'll find plenty of books, websites, and courses if you search for them.

Comment: You need to learn programming, no way around it. Python is widely considered as much easier to learn for beginners than Java is, and has excellent free online courses. It will take you likely many months to become competent programmer. Just fair warning. it is fun. Python has also excellent Selenium bindings. I write all my Selenium tests in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think learning some basic coding skills would be very beneficial.  There are many websites that will help you learn basic java and selenium skills.

If you're just looking to get in to a position and learn on the job, learning pseudo code will go a long way to getting your idea across in an interview even when you might not know the exact syntax.

One of the biggest things I've seen from interviews is that the thought process can be held with about the same value of beginner programming skills.  Be sure to explain your logic for stepping through the puzzles/quizzes and ask plenty of questions to make sure there aren't any details that you're missing.